# Django 2.1 passing a variable to template,

Tags: python, django

Have a question here about passing a variable into a Django template. The goal is to filter a set of photos based off the type of photography. I initially wanted to do it from S3 and the folder that it was in, but that's a little beyond my skill at the moment. I went with just creating different url's that account for that. The issue I'm having is that I'd like to pass the variable into the template that extends the base_layout.html, but it won't render anything for that variable. Am I just miss-understanding how to do it?

Model.py

```
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.
class Gallery(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    body = models.TextField(max_length = 500)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    thumb = models.ImageField(default = 'default.jpg', blank = True)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank = True)
    order = models.CharField(max_length = 2, blank = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def body_preview(self):
        return self.body[:50]

class photoUrl(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(max_length = 128)
    uploaded_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

class Photos(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    picture = models.ImageField(blank = True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    catagory = models.CharField(max_length=256, choices=[('wedding', 'wedding'), ('portrait', 'portrait'), ('landscape', 'landscape'), ('boudoir', 'boudoir'),], blank = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.urls import reverse
from . models import Photos

# Create your views here.


def photo_wedding(request):
    photo_list = Photos.objects.filter(catagory = 'wedding').order_by('created')
    photoCat = 'Wedding'
    return render(request, 'gallery/gallery.html', {'photo_list' : photo_list}, {'photoCat' : photoCat})
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name='gallery'

urlpatterns = [
    path('wedding/', views.photo_wedding, name='wedding'),
    path('portrait/', views.photo_portrait, name='portrait'),
    path('landscape/', views.photo_landscape, name='landscape'),
    path('boudoir/', views.photo_boudoir, name='boudoir'),
]
```

gallery.html

```
{% extends 'gallery/base_layout.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block gallery %}

    <div class="gallery" id="gallery">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="w3l-heading">

                <h3>{{photoCat}}</h3>

                <div class="w3ls-border"> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
{% endblock gallery %}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the definition of [render](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#render):

> `render(request, template_name, context=None, content_type=None, status=None, using=None)`
>   Combines a given template with a given context dictionary and returns an HttpResponse object with that rendered text.

the render method takes the first parameter as a `request`, the second parameter as `template_name` and the third parameter is a `context` which is of type dictionary you choose to pass to the template, you can access all the values of dictionary with the key.

So your method should look like below:

```
def photo_wedding(request):
    photo_list = Photos.objects.filter(catagory = 'wedding').order_by('created')
    photoCat = 'Wedding'
    return render(request, 'gallery/gallery.html', {'photo_list' : photo_list, 'photoCat' : photoCat})
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you passing two dictionaries. Just add a key. That is the context data.

In class based views you can also overload the method `get_context_data`

Comment: Got it, thanks! Can't believe I was doing that. Kid being sick for three days takes its mental toll I guess.

Answer (score 0):

With the [`render()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) function, the third argument is the context. The context is a dictionary used to send variable to templates. No need to pass two dicts

```
def photo_wedding(request):
    photo_list = Photos.objects.filter(catagory = 'wedding').order_by('created')
    photoCat = 'Wedding'
```

```
    context = {'photo_list' : photo_list,'photoCat' : photoCat}
    return render(request, 'gallery/gallery.html', context)
```